# Search Bar in Django?

Tags: python, django, redirect

I have a bootstrap search bar and I want it to search for a list of all **tags** in a database. **Tags** are a like a facebook page or reddit tags.

When I submit my search, I want the URL to include the GET-parameter: `?q="typeword"`, but the application has to redirect to a new page, and preserve the tags parameter while doing so.  How can I do this?

I have tried using GET-request and paginator, but nothing seems to work. I can add a new URL "search/" and then it works, but only with this url.

### models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    path = models.CharField(max_length=37,default=0)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg',upload_to='tag_pics')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.path
```

### views.py

```
def search(request):

    q = request.GET.get('q',None)
    items=''

    if q is None or q is "":
        items = Tag.objects.all()

    elif q is not None:
        items = Tag.objects.filter(name__contains=q)

    paginator = Paginator(items, 3)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    items = paginator.get_page(page)

    title = "Search"

    return render(request, 'blog/search.html',{'items': items, 'title': title})
```

### search.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  {% if items %}
    <p class="search-count">Found 
      <strong> 
        {{ items.paginator.count }}
      </strong> 
      result{{ items.paginator.count|pluralize }}
    </p>
    {% for i in items %}
      {{ i.path }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% elif request.GET.q %}
    <p class="search-no-results">
      No results for "<strong>{{ request.GET.q }}"
    </p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Instead of redirecting the users, won't it be better to use an autocomplete dropdown? [Creating Autocomplete Dropdowns with the Datalist Element](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/creating-autocomplete-dropdowns-datalist-element)

Comment: Can we see the code for your form? ... If you have a malfunctioning `<form>` (for instance without an 'action'-method, then that could result in what you're experiencing. Your form should be like: `<form method="get" ... `, if you want it to add a get-request, upon submitting.